# Output of question does not include all parts of it

Tags: support, markdown

The output on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25298505/1503018) is strange.

This is what is entered in the editor:

```
   at runtime if else is not working
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var r=confirm("Do u want to change?");
    if (r==true)
     {
    x=6;
    }
    else
    {
     x=0;
     }
     <?php $b="<script>document.write(x)</script>"; ?>
     </script>
     <?php 
     if(isset ($b))
     {
     echo $b;
     if($b!=0)
     {
     echo"Change";
     }
    else
     {
     echo "Do not change";
      }
      }
      ?>
```

But this is what is shown on the question:

> at runtime if else is not working
>       
>       var r=confirm("Do u want to change?");
>       if (r==true)
>        {
>       x=6;
>       }
>       else
>       {
>        x=0;
>        }
>        document.write(x)"; ?>

You can also see effect if you have the ability to edit this question.

I have fixed this question, and [revison](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25298505/revisions) of it could be demonstrative.

[image: side-by-side markdown revision]
[image: side-by-side revision]

Two symbols makes huge changes. I think that missing of text is bug.

Comment: blame < and >....

Comment: A look at the actual content (both by viewing and by attempting to edit) does not include anything more than what is displayed and quoted above. I don't see the `var` portion you've indicated is missing in either place. I don't know where you think the additional content is located, but it's not in the submitted question. (I don't see any misplaced <> or incorrect formatting when viewed in the edit window.)

Comment: @KenWhite, try to edit this question.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to that is not showing? This question needs to be made clearer.

Comment: @sectus: I did, and I don't see any difference between the two. I have sufficient privileges to edit the question, so I should be able to see it. I don't.

Comment: @KenWhite , can you see it now? It's really hard to show things that not showed : )

Comment: @KenWhite I think he's talking about why line breaks are ignored in the output.

Comment: @Anonymous Half of the text is missing for me.  Everything between `document.write(x)` and the final `?>` is gone (plus the `<?php...`)

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Good point. I guess that must be what he is referring to.

Comment: Block elements (e.g. [code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode)) in markdown need to be preceded by one or more blank lines.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, I know how to format code. It's true, this question was not properly formated. So, whole text have to be shown as simple text, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking.  If you're concerned about why so much of the content went missing when it wasn't properly formatted as code, it's because our html sanitizer is pretty liberal with what it removes.

Comment: @JarrodDixon , Text is missing. Is it normal behaviour or not?

Comment: Yes, it is normal - the text is heavily sanitized when blacklisted html elements are encountered, e.g. `<script>`.

Comment: @JarrodDixon , it's an answer that I could check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how output parser works. It's remove all content from output that enclosed with `<>` that is not list of allowable tags. So, you could hide text in your answer (something like spoiler) and could be viewed by editors only.

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. You are displaying the code as invalid HTML instead of formatting it in a code block.  The first line in a continuous string of text lines has three spaces but code needs to be indented with four spaces and one blank or whitespace line before it.

Just add an extra line after the first and it will work fine:

---

at runtime if else is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var r=confirm("Do u want to change?");
if (r==true)
 {
x=6;
}
else
{
 x=0;
 }
 <?php $b="<script>document.write(x)</script>"; ?>
 </script>
 <?php 
 if(isset ($b))
 {
 echo $b;
 if($b!=0)
 {
 echo"Change";
 }
else
 {
 echo "Do not change";
  }
  }
  ?>
```

---

You could even remove the spaces before `at runtime if else is not working` if you want.

Comment: It is not my question. So, it's feature to add comments to a question for editors?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You can already add comments and can already edit other questions.

Comment: Text is missing. And could be viewed by editors only while editing. Are sure that is normal behaviour?

Comment: Unnecessary closing tags may yield unexpected behavior. Code should be indented in code blocks.

Comment: Could you give simple direct answer: Text is missing. Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: I'm saying that it may be unusual, but since code should be indented in code blocks and it is invalid HTML/JavaScript anyway, it is not really a concern. Any quality question should use proper formatting anyway.